# problema a la hora de pasar por referencia una variable

Tags: array, c, funciones, punteros, contador

tengo un problema con un programa de descriptor de archivos que estoy haciendo en C. Mi problema es que paso por referencia una variable int llamada contador inicializada en 0, en la primer funcion funciona bien.... la funcion es la siguiente:

```
void cargar_archivo(struct principal * init, int * cant, struct usuario * users, int *cont){
    int N = 0;
    int op;

    FILE *archivo;
    char name[25];
    unsigned int tamanio;

    printf("\nseguro desea cargar los datos de un nuevo archivo? 1 = si - 0 = no: ");
    scanf("%d",&op);
    while(op!=1&&op!=0){
        printf("\ningreso incorrecto, debe introducir 1 o 0.....\nIntente nuevamente:");
        scanf("%d",&op);
    }

    while(op==1&&*cont<cant){
    printf("\nIngresa el nombre del archivo: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%25s",name);
    fflush(stdin);
    validacion(name);
    while((validacion(name))==false)
    {
        printf("\nVuelva a ingresar el nombre del archivo: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        scanf("%25s",name);
        fflush(stdin);
        validacion(name);
    }
    strcpy(init->nombre,name);
    if((archivo=fopen(init->nombre,"w"))!=NULL){
        time_t current_time;
        current_time=time(NULL);
        printf("\nAsignando id automaticamente...");
        init->index = rand();// % (N+1);
        init->permiso.idOwner = users->idUsuario;
        init->permiso.idGroup = users->idGrupo;
        init->fechaCreacion = current_time;
        init->fechaUltimoAcceso = current_time;
        printf("\nIngresa el tama%co del archivo(en bytes): ",164);
        scanf("%u",&tamanio);
        init->tamanio=tamanio;
        cont++;
        init++;
    }
    else{
        printf("hubo un error al crear el archivo\n");
    }
```

el problema es que cuando quiero usarla para otra función en la cual quiero imprimir todos los datos ingresados en la primer función, es como que el contador no funcionara, es decir, me imprime lo que hay en otros indices del struct init que todavia no fueron cargados los datos:
void listar_datos(struct principal *init, struct usuario * users,int *cont){

```
for(int i=0;i<cont;i++){
    printf("\nListando datos..................");
    char creationDate[80];
    char lastAccessDate[80];
    time_t current_time;
    current_time=init->fechaCreacion;
    struct tm ts;
    ts=*localtime(&current_time);
    strftime(creationDate,sizeof(creationDate),"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S",&ts);

    printf("\nindex del archivo: %d",init->index);
    printf("\nnombre del archivo: %s",init->nombre);
    printf("\ntama%co del archivo: %u",164,init->tamanio);
    //printf("\nPermisos: %hu%hu%hu",init->permiso->acceso_Owner,init->permiso->acceso_Group,init->permiso->acceso_Other);
    if(init->permiso.idOwner==users->idUsuario){
        printf("\nUsuario: %s",users->idUsuario);
    }else{
        printf("\nUsuario no encontrado");
    }
    if(init->permiso.idGroup==users->idGrupo){
        printf("\Grupo: %s",users->idGrupo);
    }else{
        printf("\Grupo no encontrado");
    }
    printf("\nFecha de creacion: %s",creationDate);
    current_time=init->fechaUltimoAcceso;
    ts=*localtime(&current_time);
    strftime(lastAccessDate,sizeof(lastAccessDate),"%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S",&ts);
    printf("\nFecha de modificacion: %s",lastAccessDate);
    printf("\n");
    init++;
}

}
```

prototipos de funcion:

```
void cargar_archivo(struct principal *, int *,struct usuario *,int *);
void listar_datos(struct principal *,struct usuario *,int *);
```

Comment: Una cosa... tiene while(op==1&&*cont<cant) , está comparando el valor de un int (*cont) al valor de un puntero (cant), no?  Quiere (*cont < *cant) ?

Comment: hola, muchas gracias por la ayuda, ahora modifico esa linea y veo como funciona!